# why components redrawn when i override with empty paintComponent(g) method?

Tags: java

As i understand (and i am java noob), when i resize a window or change its content paintComponent() method should be called automatically. It redraws everything, so when i override it with an empty method, nothing should be redrawn...but it is. Why? Probably i am missing something. What exactly is redrawn by paintComponent(), everything? Or some backgrounds or smth?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextFrame extends JFrame {
       public TextFrame(String text, String fontName) {
       super("Show Font");
       setSize(725, 150);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       TextFramePanel sf = new TextFramePanel(text, fontName);
       JButton ok = new JButton("i hate disappearing");
       sf.add(ok);

       add(sf);
       setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    if (arguments.length < 1) {
        System.out.println("Usage: java TextFrame message font");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    TextFrame frame = new TextFrame(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
}

}

class TextFramePanel extends JPanel {
   String text;
   String fontName;

   public TextFramePanel(String text, String fontName) {
    super();
    this.text = text;
    this.fontName = fontName;
   }

public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {
    //super.paintComponent(comp);
    /*Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D)comp;
    comp2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); 
    Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 18);
    FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(font);
    comp2D.setFont(font);
    int x = (getSize().width - metrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
    int y = getSize().height / 2;
    comp2D.drawString(text, x, y);
    System.out.println("vlad");*/
}
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, override the paint method with an empty method too.

Comment: What exactly is being painted, that is unexpected?

Comment: chris, yes, when i override paint with an empty method, nothing is redrawn; but what about paintComponent? Do these methods relate to particular components? When i resize frame, painComponent is also called.

Comment: @peeskillet, in this example JButton is repainted. But i tried several codes, and everything is repainted except when component is moved, background is not repainted.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read up on the official docs for Custom Painting: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html, more importantly under the Section **A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism**.

Here's the part that's directly related to your question:

> [...] the paintComponent method is where all of your painting code should be placed. It is true that this method will be invoked when it is time to paint, but painting actually begins higher up the class heirarchy, with the paint method (defined by java.awt.Component.) This method will be executed by the painting subsystem whenever you component needs to be rendered. Its signature is:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

> [...] The API does nothing to prevent your code from overriding paintBorder
>   and paintChildren, but generally speaking, there is no reason for you
>   to do so. For all practical purposes paintComponent will be the only
>   method that you will ever need to override.

---

So, when you're declaring:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {}
```

you're **not** actually doing **nothing**. That's because the painting, as stated from the docs, does not begin with `paintComponent()`, but rather with `paint()`, which is called much earlier.

---

Now, if you declare it like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){}
```

then nothing will be redrawn after resizing and etc, no matter what code you have in your `paintComponent()`, because the beginning of the paint hierarchy has just been defined as an empty routine.

Comment: @victorantunes thx for the answer! I've read the article, but the only thing i understood is that there is some machinery with all these UIDelegates and some method hierarchy. Also that paintComponent is responsible for updating background, but paintChildren for updating components in a container. At the same time i have +100 questions, say about code here: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html .Do you have any idea on how these 2 repaint methods work? How do they figure out when to paint square, and when to paint it over with background color? But anyway, thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

> *"...so when i override it with an empty method, nothing should be redrawn...but it is. Why?"*

So it looks like you're running this program from the command line. If you are running the program, and it's still painting the stuff inside the `paintComponent` method (even after you commented out its content), most likely you ran the program with compiling again. So the program is still running from the same .class file.

When I run the program as is, I see nothing but a button, no painted words.

> `C:\stack>java TextFrame Hello World`

---

> *" What exactly is redrawn by paintComponent(), everything? Or some backgrounds or smth?"*

`paintComponent` just paint the component itself, which is just the `JPanel` in your case. It doesn't paint any other components added to it. That painting is delegated by *its* `paintComponent` method. Every `JComponent` has its own `paintComponent` method. So if you're wondering why the button still appears, it's because the call to `paintComponent` in the `JPanel` only affects the `JPanel`, not other child components add to it.

Comment: nono, i am running it from blueJay. And my problem is with JButton which is being repainted after i, say, minimize window and then open it again

Comment: I'm testing out your program and I really have no idea what you're talking about.